# Confusing type conversion error (date-to-varchar throwing string-to-datetime error)

Tags: sql-server, datetime, type-conversion

I have a table that tracks inserts, updates, and deletions to another table. This pattern has been used for years but has suddenly introduced an error when we added tracking of a `DATE` column.

This is not a string format issue. My input data is in ISO-8601 standard format.

I've cut out all but the necessary parts of the code to demonstrate the issue.

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.ChangeTrackingTable
(
    oldValue VARCHAR(100) NULL,
    newValue VARCHAR(100) NULL
);
GO
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.usp_TestProcedure
(
    @name VARCHAR(100),
    @dateOfBirth DATE
)
AS
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO dbo.ChangeTrackingTable
    (
        oldValue,
        newValue
    )
    SELECT
        List.oldFieldValue,
        List.newFieldValue
    FROM
        (VALUES
            (NULL, @name, IIF(@name IS NOT NULL, 1, 0)),
            (NULL, @dateOfBirth, IIF(@dateOfBirth IS NOT NULL, 1, 0))
        ) AS List (oldFieldValue, newFieldValue, hasChanges)
    WHERE
        List.hasChanges = 1
END;
GO
```

The `VALUES` list is used to dynamically determine which columns are being touched.

When I execute the sproc with just the date, everything works fine.

```
DECLARE @date DATE = GETDATE();

EXEC dbo.usp_TestProcedure
    @name = NULL,
    @dateOfBirth = @date;

/*
oldValue    newValue
NULL    2019-03-27
*/
```

But if I try to execute it with any value supplied for `@name`, whether or not a value for `@date` is supplied, I get the following error.

```
DECLARE @date DATE = GETDATE();

EXEC dbo.usp_TestProcedure
    @name = 'Name',
    @dateOfBirth = @date;

--Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.
```

If I supply hard-coded values directly to the `INSERT` statement, it works fine. So I can know it's not happening at the table level on insert.

If I add an explicit cast to this line

```
(NULL, CAST(@dateOfBirth AS VARCHAR(100)), IIF(@dateOfBirth IS NOT NULL, 1, 0))
```

it works as well.

The problem occurs with `DATETIMEOFFSET`, `DATETIME`, and `DATETIME2` types as well, so my use of `DATE` is not the issue.

My question is why am I getting a `string > datetime` conversion error when I'm trying to read a `DATE` value to be inserted into a `VARCHAR` column, but only in a `VALUES` list when there exists another non-date value in the result-set for `List`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In refining the question itself to its basic structure, I discovered the underlying answer.

When using the pattern

```
SELECT *
FROM
    (VALUES
        (NULL, @name, IIF(@name IS NOT NULL, 1, 0)),
        (NULL, @dateOfBirth, IIF(@dateOfBirth IS NOT NULL, 1, 0))
    ) AS List (oldFieldValue, newFieldValue, hasChanges)
```

SQL Server will need to create a table in memory, and each of those columns needs an assigned datatype. This datatype is not assigned arbitrarily, but methodically according to a well-documented order of [Data Type Precedence](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/data-type-precedence-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017).

All the date-types appear very high in this list, so my use of `DATE` takes precedence over any `CHAR` or `VARCHAR` type that also appears in the table.

The column in my `List` table is assigned the highest-precedence type: `DATE`.

The error is being thrown when the `VARCHAR` value, `'Name'` is being implicitly cast to the data-type of the column, which is `DATE`. Not when the `@date` parameter is inserted into the `VARCHAR` column of the table.